# async task null error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

I'm currently working with an async task that parses a JSON string. Once the string is parsed and the task from doInBackground() moves on to postExecute() it's giving me this error:

```
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:356)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at stefan.testservice.ParkingActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(ParkingActivity.java:258)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-17 20:19:53.612: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It was working perfectly before, just all of a sudden it's seems to have some problem with the 'return null' statement at the end of the async task. I can't seem to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

My code snippet:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.i("MyApp", "Background thread starting");

            Global.url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/CarServiceScheduling1/resources/json/product/getpark?degree="+degreeStatus+"&year="+yearStatus+"&distance="+distance+"&devid="+Global.android_id;

            try{
                statusCode = cg.connection();    
            }catch (Exception e) {
                test_connection  = true;
            }


            if(test_connection == false){

                try {
                    output = cg.stringconverter(Global.data);
                    cg.parseGson(output);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }



protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

                if (ParkingActivity.this.progressDialog != null) {
                    ParkingActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if(CheckboxPreference == true && Integer.parseInt(Global.preference1) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(Global.preference2) == 0 && (Global.status.equalsIgnoreCase("No Slots available") || Global.status.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))){


                        Intent searchSubActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                Nospotsactivity.class);
                        startActivity(searchSubActivity);
                    }
                    else if (CheckboxPreference == true && (Integer.parseInt(Global.preference1) != 0 || Integer.parseInt(Global.preference2) != 0 )){

                        Intent searchSubActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                Spotsfoundactivity.class);
                        startActivity(searchSubActivity);
                    }   
                    else if(CheckboxPreference == false && (Integer.parseInt(Global.preference1) != 0 || Integer.parseInt(Global.preference2) != 0 )){


                        Intent searchSubActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                Spotsfoundactivity.class);
                        startActivity(searchSubActivity);
                    }
                    if(Integer.parseInt(Global.preference1) == 0 && Integer.parseInt(Global.preference2) == 0){

                        if(Global.status.equalsIgnoreCase("Hardly Likely")){


                            Intent searchSubActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                    Unlikelyactivity.class);
                            startActivity(searchSubActivity);
                        }


                        else if(Global.status.equalsIgnoreCase("Likely")){


                            Intent searchSubActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                    Likelyactivity.class);
                            startActivity(searchSubActivity);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see first line `unable to parse 'null' as integer` so first check string is null or not before parsing to integer

Comment: can you kindly elaborate please as I didn't understand exactly what you're saying

Comment: He's saying that the relevant part of the log is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer`. You're passing a null to something. Check for null before passing it.

Comment: post some  code from line number 340 to 375

Comment: can u post postExecute() code part?

Comment: ok solved guys I had the Global.pref1 variable not set and hence was null, thanks for your kind help

Comment: check Global.preference1 and other variables before parsing to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace, Either `Global.preference1` or `Global.preference2` is null (or both). You may want to do a null check before parsing them as integers.